# Change a text view using the onclick activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a main activity that shows three buttons another xml with a text view. 
How do I change the text of the second one when a button is clicked? 
 I could make a different onClick action n Activities of each of them, but I want to do this with less lines of codes.

Comment: Your question seems to be unclear. provide some more information and code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Button reference.

```
Button B1;
textView t1;
```

Now Use the onCLick function of this button to change the text of your textview.

```
B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
              t1.setText("Whatever you want; That is the new text. ");

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

To minimalize lines of code do the following

1 implement View.OnClickListener in your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
```

2 In onCreate() add buttons:

```
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1_id);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2_id);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3_id);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

3 Add onClick method to Activity

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1_id:
            // button 1 action
            break;
        case R.id.button2_id:
            // button 2 action
            break;
        case R.id.button3_id:
            // button 3 action
            break;

    }
}
```